# How to write Grep command for this case?

Tags: linux, grep, command

I am not Grep guy, and ask question here to get the grep command to resolve this problem quickly.

Given html text like these,

```
<tr><td class="font_face" style="font-family:HelveticaNeue">HelveticaNeue</td><td class="iphone">3.0</td><td class="ipad">4.3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="font_face" style="font-family:HelveticaNeue-Bold">HelveticaNeue-Bold</td><td class="iphone">3.0</td><td class="ipad">4.3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="font_face" style="font-family:HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic">HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic</td><td class="iphone">3.0</td><td class="ipad">4.3</td></tr>
```

Need grep commend to get the output like these

```
HelveticaNeue 
HelveticaNeue-Bold 
HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic
```

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `grep`, you could say:

```
grep -Po '(?<=font-family:).*?(?=")' filename
```

For your input, it'd return:

```
HelveticaNeue
HelveticaNeue-Bold
HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic
```

EDIT: As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900748/how-to-write-grep-command-for-this-case#comment31371623_20900799) by [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent), you could also say:

```
grep -Po '(?<=font-family:)[^"]*' filename
```

Comment: +1 nice look around. this could be shorter (and faster?): `'(?<=...)[^"]*' `

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '{gsub(/<[^>]*>/,FS);print $1}' file
HelveticaNeue
HelveticaNeue-Bold
HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic
```

This `awk` removes everything between `<` and  `>`
It gives `HelveticaNeue 3.0 4.3`, we then print field `#1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl as well:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/font-family:([^\"]*)\"/)' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Your Data Contains in Test.html file

Then You can use below command:

```
 cat Test.html | awk  -F  '">' '{print $2}' | awk -F "</" '{print $1}'
```

Output:

```
HelveticaNeue
HelveticaNeue-Bold
HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic
```